# Reg : Id to Long

Tags: apex

I have salesforce record ID.Can any help me how to convert ID to long 
in Apex. Convert Record ID to Long variable

Comment: It's not directly possible since a long is a number and Salesforce Ids contain letters.

Comment: @martin  Can you plz give me suggestion how to convert this

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the numbers, it looks like you might not even be able to do this.

Each Id has unique alphanumeric identifier that is a 9 digit base 62 number. When you multiply that by the number of objects there are currently, about 1216 if I counted it up right, you get ~1.64611E+19, which is just barely under the number of numbers that a long can support, 2^64 ~1.84467E+19.

If you wanted to factor in the pod number or that reserved space, or the number of objects increases, there will be more possible Ids that you want to represent than there are longs.

This is a great reference on Ids by the way: http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can cast an Id to a long unless you start doing some uncomfortable bitwise operations. @martin 's post above also shows why it might not be possible.

The most common conversion is from ID to String and vice versa.

It might be helpful if you told us what you want to achieve by converting it to a long.